# localStorage removal in Firefox and IE

Tags: firefox, local-storage

I understand removing `localStorage' from Chrome is a bit tricky. Instead I am using FF to store my values during development.

Please provide me steps to remove localStorage in FF settings. Obviously, removing just the cache wouldn't work.

I cannot use `localStorage.removeItem['key']` in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `localStorage.removeItem(key);` (note the parenthesis instead of square brackets), and if you want to remove all the items in localStorage use `localStorage.clear();`